# MySQL is turning ™ into ª?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm exporting an excel file into a CSV and then uploading to a MySQL database, but every entry that has a ™ (trademark) turns into a small a (ª).

The database is set to utf8_unicode_ci, as is each row. Any ideas why this is happening still?

Comment: I've had the same type of issues, and seem to have better luck using PHP to load the data.

Comment: What encoding is Excel using for the export? My guess is, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to do the conversion. If you use Windows, you can download a text editor like Notepad++ for free, and Notepad++ can encode or convert a text file into UTF-8 (on the menu bar, go to Encoding, switch to whichever one you want).

The same is also possible with a Mac editor like TextMate. File > Re-Open With Encoding.

Excel does indeed automatically encode a file **generated** from Excel in the Windows format. However, if it is used to open a file that uses a different encoding, it should preserve that encoding; it won't convert UTF-8 encoded files into Windows-1252.

Comment: Yup - a handy workaround if the file isn't being directly uploaded, etc.

Comment: Just one more reason I get fed up with Microsoft products! The information shows up a bit jumbled on the backend of the database, but prints out fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there's a 1-1 replacement in the mojibake, it's unlikely that UTF-8 is involved.

It appears that the original data was in one of the [Macintosh encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aMac_OS_character_encodings) where '™' encodes to 0xAA, and got misinterpreted as [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) ([windows-1254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) and [-1258](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) and [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), [-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9), and [-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) are also possible) where 0xAA decodes to 'ª'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Excel CSV file is (most likely) in Windows-1252 format.

As such, you'll most likely need to use PHP to convert each item into UTF-8 format using a function such as [mb_convert_variables](http://www.php.net/mb_convert_variables)

For example:

```
$utfVersion = mb_convert_variables('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $windowsVersion);
```

Incidentally, it *might* still show up incorrectly if you view the MySQL table via the command line tools, etc., but it'll be fine once you retrieve it back into PHP.